# Unable to access ssrs reports from another machine using the URL in same network

Tags: networking, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created and deployed an SSRS report 2008, which I am able to access from the same machine using the URL. But I am not able to access the URL from another machine in the same network. Please suggest me what i have to do to access SSRS reports via URL from another machine in Local Area Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to access an SSRS report is generally dependent on Windows authentication, which is controlled under the report manager's security tab. You can add or remove groups of users through the security interface. This would explain why some users can access it and others cannot. Also, when granting access, you must be sure the user has the Browser role enabled.

If it is a permissions issue, then SSRS should return a permissions error when you attempt to access it from the other terminal.

Therefore, you need to ensure that all intended users are in an appropriate user group and granted the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the report by accessing report manager from your browser. Report manager url is the one we set up while installing and configuring ssrs.